# Why do I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'` in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

Code:

```
def rotate(self, head, k):
   
    temp=head
    while temp !=None:
        temp=temp.next
    temp.next=head
    while k<=0:
        temp=temp.next
        k=k-1
    head=temp.next
    temp.next=None
    return head
```

Runtime Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/e0077f38d79613307f6605d73ec359f5.py", line 69, in 
> head = Solution().rotate(lis.head,k)   File "/home/e0077f38d79613307f6605d73ec359f5.py", line 21, in rotate
> temp.next=head AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'

How can I fix this?